# NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue NullReferenceException in WP7.5

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I would like to pass a string between to pages in 7.5

I have read some guides, but, I have a `NullReferenceException` .

Page.xml.cs :

```
 var item = ListBoxTiers.SelectedItem as CTiers; 
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailTiers.xaml?selectedItem=" + item.m_strCode, UriKind.Relative));
```

If i look at the debugger, i can see :  `"DetailTiers.xaml?selectedItem=C0000015"`

In my page , Page2.xms.cs:

```
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string strCodeTiers =   string.Empty;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem",out strCodeTiers)) // Exception here
        {

        }
```

Anyone know where is my error ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't call this code from the constructor, as the `NavigationContext` isn't initialized yet. Use the `OnNavigatedTo` event instead:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string strCodeTiers = string.Empty;

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem",out strCodeTiers))
    {
         // Whatever
    }
}
```